How do I type hint a frame object in Python?
I'm type hinting a large existing Python codebase, and in one part it sets a signal handler using signal.signal. The signal handler is a custom function defined in the codebase, so I need to type hint it myself. However, while I can guess based on the description of signal.signal that the first parameter is an integer, the second one is just described as "None or a frame object" in the documentation.
I have no idea what a frame object is, but thankfully the aforementioned documentation links to a section called "Frame objects" and the inspect module documentation. However, after looking through both of these, I still don't really find any information about how to actually type hint a frame object, just information that might be useful to someone writing code that interacts with frame objects without typing it.
So, what type do I use for frame object type hints in Python?

types.FrameType is what you are looking for.

Beat me to it while I was fixing a typo...lol

The types module defines a FrameType

For me types.FrameType wasn't enough. I had to add | None to make Pylance happy:
def handler(signum: int, frame: types.FrameType | None):


Yes, same for me. I just didn't want to make the question specific to signal.signal but rather frame objects in general.
